# ReadInt64 can only be called when CurrentBsonType is Int64, not when CurrentBsonType is Int32

Tags: c#, asp.net, mongodb, deserialization

i am storing the ReceiveDate field as Array type in MongoDb And in the code, i  am using the DateTimeOffset datatype for the associated field.

While performing the Deserialization, i get the below error  :

> An error occurred while deserializing the ReceiveDate property of
> class Models.ServiceEvent: ReadInt64 can only be called when
> CurrentBsonType is Int64, not when CurrentBsonType is Int32. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: ReadInt64 can only be called when
> CurrentBsonType is Int64, not when CurrentBsonType is Int32.    at
> MongoDB.Bson.IO.BsonReader.VerifyBsonType(String methodName, BsonType
> requiredBsonType)

MongoDb Field :
[image: MongoDb Field]

My deserialization Method :

```
public override DateTimeOffset Deserialize(BsonDeserializationContext context, 
   BsonDeserializationArgs args)
{
    var bsonReader = context.Reader;
    long ticks;
    TimeSpan offset = new TimeSpan(0);

    BsonType bsonType = bsonReader.GetCurrentBsonType();
    switch (bsonType)
    {
       
        case BsonType.Array:
                bsonReader.ReadStartArray();
                ticks = bsonReader.ReadInt64();
            
            
            try
            {
                offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(bsonReader.ReadInt32());
            }
            catch
            {
                bsonReader.ReadDouble();
                offset = new TimeSpan(0);
            }
            bsonReader.ReadEndArray();
            return new DateTimeOffset(ticks, offset);

        case BsonType.Document:
            ticks = 0;
            offset = TimeSpan.Zero;
            _helper.DeserializeMembers(context, (elementName, flag) =>
            {
                switch (flag)
                {
                    case Flags.DateTime: bsonReader.SkipValue(); break; // ignore value
                    case Flags.Ticks: ticks = _int64Serializer.Deserialize(context); break;
                    case Flags.Offset: offset = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(_int32Serializer.Deserialize(context)); break;
                }
            });
            return new DateTimeOffset(ticks, offset);

        case BsonType.String:
            return JsonConvert.ToDateTimeOffset(bsonReader.ReadString());

        default:
            throw CreateCannotDeserializeFromBsonTypeException(bsonType);
    }
}
```

Model.cs Property :

```
public DateTimeOffset ReceiveDate { get; set; }
```

Can anyone please help me with this error ?

Comment: Use `ReadInt32()` instead?

Comment: I tried Using it. But the issue is , i cant seem to use ReadStartArray() with Int32 type .

Comment: I doubt it's true what you said above

Answer (score 0):

You can analyze the data type of the current field before reading it, like:

```
case BsonType.Array:
  bsonReader.ReadStartArray();
  if (bsonReader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Int64)
    ticks = bsonReader.ReadInt64();
  else if (bsonReader.CurrentBsonType == BsonType.Int32)
    ticks = (long)bsonReader.ReadInt32();
  else
    throw ...
```